# How to sync addressbook using contacts framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact, cncontactstore

I want to sync my contacts in my app automatically if updated in the phone contacts.

for example.

I have 5 contacts. if i update the mobile number of the first contact i don't want to update my database fully again. I just want to update the particular contact alone.

or

If a new contact is added.I want to add that particular contact alone.

Note :- I'm using CN contacts  Framework for fetching and displaying contacts.

Comment: Any updates on this...? Did you find your solution...?

Comment: No updates. Hoping to find a solution soon

Comment: you can do it by CNContactIdentifierKey to get unique identifier and update any particular record @NishanthKumar

Comment: any example on how to use contact identifier key @VivekGoswami in objective c

Comment: ya sure here is link for code what i have done in my app https://dpaste.de/7JgY @NishanthKumar

Comment: I mean like whats app contacts. if a user deletes a contact from device, it immediately reflects in whatsapp contacts. how to do that?? @VivekGoswami

Comment: when it delete from device. you have to reload your contact list in your app, so it only display which is exist in contacts..@NishanthKumar